# Error:(35, 56) error: incompatible types: <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk, mobile-development

Здравствуйте. Недавно решил заниматься созданием мобильных приложений через среду разработки **Android Studio**. Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать программу, которая по клику кнопки вызывает уведомление, однако студия "ругается" на ключевое слово **this**. Код проекта следующий:

```
    package com.arslee07.notificationsntoast;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        View.OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
                builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                builder.setContentTitle("Title");
                builder.setContentText("Notification text");

                Notification notification = builder.build();

                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
            }
        };


        button.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);



    }
}
```

Прошу помочь, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить

```
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

на

```
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```